# How to validate the values retrieved from an ajx call in a handler?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string method = context.Request["method"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
        {
            switch (method)
            {
                case "getReportGroups":
                    {
                    long projectId = long.Parse(context.Request.Params["projectId"]);
                        if (projectId > 0)
                            SerializeResults(getReportGroups(projectId), null, false, context);
                        else
                        {
                            ThrowInvalidProjectIdException(projectId);
                        }
                    }
}}
```

I want to validate the projectId that is retrieved and stored in the variable "long projectId". If suppose it is passed as a string or something, i am getting an exception. So how to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not certain that it will be a long when you cast it, you can use TryParse instead.

```
long projectId;
if(long.TryParse(context.Request.Params["projectId"], out projectId)
{
    if (projectId > 0)
        SerializeResults(getReportGroups(projectId), null, false, context);
    else
    {
        ThrowInvalidProjectIdException(projectId);
    }
}
else
{
    //Handle the case where projectId could not be parsed as a long
}
```